# Why do tuple structs and enum variants behave like functions

Tags: rust

It looks like it's about binding a type constructor to a variable, but I haven't seen in in a wild and compiler accepts it like it's normal. So that's why I'm asking.

Thanks in advance!

[link to playgroud](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8f9df7d8fd0f2bea7baf981e680917a2)

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
struct B(u8);

#[derive(Debug)]
enum E {
    A(u8),
}

fn main() {
    let y = E::A;
    let y = y(0);
    dbg!(y);

    let x = B;
    let x = x(0);
    dbg!(x);

    // uncomment to see compiler complain
    // let c: fn(u8) -> u8 = B;
}
```

**UPD:**
Just recalled what made me curious. It's code block from [Rust 1.66.0 Announce](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/12/15/Rust-1.66.0.html), which I also find very confusing.

```rs
#[repr(u8)]
enum Foo {
    A(u8),
    B(i8),
    C(bool) = 42,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They behave like that because the compiler is designed that way.

Tuple-like structs and tuple-like enum variants can both be used as zero-sized values of their respective function item type.

And those, in turn, can be coerced into function pointers, which is what `c` is declared as when you assign a type of `fn(_) -> _`.

This is documented here: [The Rust Reference - Function item types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-item.html).

Answer (score 2):

For tuple structs & enum variants the compiler will define a function with the same name as the struct/variant for convenience. It allows for easy wrapping of collections in a struct / variant like this:

```rust
let ints = vec![1u8, 2, 3, 4];
let bs = ints.iter().copied().map(B).collect::<Vec<_>>();
let as = ints.iter().copied().map(E::A).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

It's probably also there to avoid confusion where one can just omit the parentheses for some identifiers but not for others.